# How to get all AD groups for particular user

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jndi

Hello I want to know if it possible to get all the groups of AD which is part of a user using, for example, the JNDI API.
Thanks

Oronzo

Answer (score 1):

This should work.
[All Groups a User is a member of including Nested groups](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+User+Related+Searches-AllGroupsAUserIsAMemberOfIncludingNestedGroups)